# Method similar to 'startswith' in Jinja2/Flask

Tags: flask, jinja2

I'm looking for method/way which is similar to python's startswith.
What I would like to do is link some fields in table which start with "i-".

My steps:

1. I have created filter, which return True/False:

   ```
   @app.template_filter('startswith')
   def starts_with(field):
       if field.startswith("i-"):
               return True
       return False
   ```

then linked it to template:

```
{% for field in row %}
            {% if {{ field | startswith }} %}
               <td><a href="{{ url_for('munin') }}">{{ field | table_field | safe }}</a></td>
            {% else %}
               <td>{{ field | table_field | safe}}</td>
            {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
```

Unfortunatetly, it doesn't work.

Second step. I did it without filter, but in template

```
{% for field in row %}
            {% if field[:2] == 'i-' %}
               <td><a href="{{ url_for('munin') }}">{{ field | table_field | safe }}</a></td>
            {% else %}
               <td>{{ field | table_field | safe}}</td>
            {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
```

That works, but to that template are sending different datas, and it works only for this case. I'm thinking that [:2] could be buggy a little bit.

So I try to write filter or maybe there is some method which I skip in documentation.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Internal Server Error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `{% if {{ field | startswith }} %}` will not work because you cannot nest blocks inside each other. You can probably get away with `{% if (field|startswith) %}` but a [custom test](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#custom-tests) rather than a filter, would be a better solution.

Something like

```
def is_link_field(field):
    return field.startswith("i-"):

environment.tests['link_field'] = is_link_field
```

Then in your template, you can write `{% if field is link_field %}`

Comment: everyone please look at the answer below

Answer (score 107):

A better solution....

You can use startswith directly in *field* because *field* is a python String.

```
{% if field.startswith('i-') %}
```

More, you can use any String function, including `str.endswith()`, for example.

Comment: What is .name referring to here?

Comment: That was a mistake. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

In Jinja2, you can use regex_search() to do a regular expression test of your string:

```
field | regex_search("^i-")
```

will return true if your string has "i-" and the beginning of the line represented by the caret "^" symbol.

Comment: `regex_search` is an ansible filter, not part of Jinja2.