# How to iterate over attributes of an object using Jinja

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model for coffee beans that I send over to my `HTML` pages and display the objects' data. Currently, I have a solution that requires me to update my `HTML` code if I modify my `Bean` object.

I want to the remove coupling from my program by iterating over the attributes associated with the object as opposed to hard-coding each attribute into the `HTML`.

My current (outdated) solution:

```
# Bean model defined using Flask-SQLAlchemy
class Bean(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), index=True, nullable=False)
    ...
```

```
<!-- some_page.html -->
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                ...
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for bean in beans %}
            {% include '_bean_info.html' %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
</table>
```

```
<!-- _bean_info.html -->
<tr>
    <th scope="col">{{ bean.id }}</th>
    <th scope="col">{{ bean.name }}</th>
    ...
</tr>
```

What I am trying to do:

```
<!-- _bean_info.html -->
<tr>
    {% for each b in bean %}
        <th scope="col">
            {{ bean.b }} <!-- where 'b' is an attribute, e.g. 'name' -->
        </th>
</tr>
```

Comment: How is your `bean` model defined?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your data structure looks like, you may be able to take advantage of the fact that the attributes of an object are available via the `__dict__` attribute...in other words, if we have data like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Bean:
    id: str
    name: str


beans = [
        Bean(id=1, name="Guatemalan"),
        Bean(id=2, name="Peruvian"),
        Bean(id=3, name="Hawaiian"),
        ]
```

Then we can use that in a template like this:

```
import jinja2

t = jinja2.Template('''
<table>
{% for bean in beans %}
<tr>
{% for attr in bean.__dict__.keys() -%}
    <td>{{ attr }}</td><td>{{ bean[attr] }}</td>
{% endfor -%}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
''')

print(t.render(beans=beans))
```

Put together, the examples above will produce:

```
<table>

<tr>
<td>id</td><td>1</td>
<td>name</td><td>Guatemalan</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>id</td><td>2</td>
<td>name</td><td>Peruvian</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>id</td><td>3</td>
<td>name</td><td>Hawaiian</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

...which is I think what you want.

---

In this particular situation, I would probably explicitly convert my model into a `dict`, because this makes the template a little less magical:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

...

t = jinja2.Template('''
<table>
{% for bean in beans %}
<tr>
{% for attr in bean.keys() -%}
    <td>{{ attr }}</td><td>{{ bean[attr] }}</td>
{% endfor -%}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
''')

print(t.render(beans=(asdict(bean) for bean in beans)))
```

Comment: This solution somewhat works. It doesn't work in its current state, but I can use the concept, I think. One of the few issues I am having with it, though, is that it prints the object's location - is there anyway to ignore certain attributes?

Comment: @JakeJackson you can use [`startswith` in jinja](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43058043/5747944). Maybe `{% if not attr.startswith('_') %}` or declare a variable which is a sequence of the attributes you _do_ want.

Comment: Thank you, that does help. However, another issue I have is the rows do not match up with the headings of the table. I print just `attr` to test this and they are completely mismatched, not even just the correct order but shifted across.

Comment: If you are explicitly defining your column names, then just put them in a variable as @sytech suggested, and use that both to generate the column headers as well select which attributes to get from the object. Otherwise, get the column names from the the first item in your `beans` list (e.g. `beans.0.keys()`).